# sort list (own defined values, other values)

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a large number of lists which I know will contain several known and several unknown (i.e. varying) entries. I would now like to sort the lists in a way that the expected entries are moved to the beginning in a predefined order, and the other entries pushed to the end (in their original order or, ideally, in alphabetical order).

For example, I have lists like these:

```
l1 = ['Agree', 'Neither agree nor disagree', 'some random answer', 'Strongly agree', 'Disagree', 'Strongly disagree']
l2 = ['Agree', '-99', 'Neither agree nor disagree', 'Strongly agree', 'Disagree', 'Strongly disagree']
l3 = ['Other', 'Agree', 'Neither agree nor disagree', 'Strongly agree', 'Disagree', 'Strongly disagree']
l4 = ['Agree', 'Neither agree nor disagree', 'Strongly agree', 'Disagree', 'Strongly disagree', 'Answer declined']
```

I would like all of the lists to be sorted in a predefined way:

```
l_out = ['Strongly agree', 'Agree', 'Neither agree nor disagree', 'Disagree', 'Strongly disagree', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']`
```

With X, Y, and Z substituting the various elements that are not present in all lists.

I could not find a question treating this and manually iterating over the list seems too troublesome to be the most efficient solution. Would be happy about any pointers - thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Could you give each element a weighting? `l1 = [('Strongly agree', 0), ('Agree', 1), ...]` then you can sort by its weighting. Or You could just store the list in the order you want it (that would probably be the easiest).

Comment: Just cut the list into two pieces. First list your non values - sort them. Second list, sort it alphabetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> l_out = ['Strongly agree', 'Agree', 'Neither agree nor disagree', 'Disagree', 'Strongly disagree']
>>> l1 = ['Agree', 'Neither agree nor disagree', 'some random answer', 'Strongly agree', 'Disagree', 'Strongly disagree']
>>> tmp1 = {k:v for v, k in enumerate(l_out)}
>>> l1.sort(key = lambda x: tmp1.get(x, len(tmp1) + 1))
>>> l1
['Strongly agree', 'Agree', 'Neither agree nor disagree', 'Disagree', 'Strongly disagree', 'some random answer']
```

Comment: This deals very elegantly with the problem of non-expected entries. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
sorted(list_to_sort, key=ranking_list.index)
```

Where `ranking_list` contains the order you want elements to appear in (i.e.`l_out` in your question).

You can also assign a default behavior for values which aren't in your ranking list, but it requires a more complex key:

```
rank_list = [...]  # Fill as needed

def rank(e, ranking=rank_list):
    try:
        return ranking.index(e)
    except ValueError:  # e was not in the ranking list
        return len(ranking)

sorted(list_to_sort, key=rank)
```